# download video with byte range python pycurl

Tags: python, video, download, range, pycurl

hello guys i am trying to download video as two or more piece. so i have written program for that reason. it worked perfectly acurate like clock at bytes but there is problem when i download movie from start at middle point it works(playable) but other half does not work :D and why i don't understand can it be fixed? i will provide now program source code and u can play around

```js
import pycurl
import time
from threading import Thread
global url
percent = 1000
total = 0
downloaded = 0

def run():
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL,"http://some video link here.mp4")
    fp= open("just file output name here.mp4", "wb")
    c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, fp)
    #range metter 1 megabyte is 1048576 byte just for knowladge
    c.setopt(c.RANGE, '5242880-52428800') 
    c.setopt(c.NOPROGRESS, 0)
    c.setopt(c.PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress)
    c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 0)
    print("starting download,happy waiting..")
    c.perform()
    

def progress(download_t, download_d, upload_t, upload_d):
        global percent
        global total
        global downloaded
        
        
        percent = (download_d+0.00000000001)/(download_t+0.000000000001)*100
        total =  (download_t/1048576) 
        downloaded = (download_d/1048576)
def main():
    
    
   

        while percent != 101:
            if percent != 1000:
                
                
                
                
                    try:
                        print ("downloaded",round(percent),"%","downloaded",round(downloaded),"from",round(total))
                        if percent == 100:
                            print("")
                            print("Download complete:")
                            break
                        time.sleep(2) 

                

                    except:
                        print("unknown error")




if __name__ == "__main__":
 
 t1 = Thread(target=run)
 t1.start()
 t2 = Thread(target=main)
 t2.start()
```

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge both the files , the second half wont play because the file has no header for the media players, the header will remain in the first half of the file.